# how to use fluentd to collect data from a service

Tags: fluentd

I'm new to fluentd.

I have a Java-DropWizard.io service running in a docker environment.
I can ask this service for a bunch of metrics data in json format by `curl http://ip:PORT/admin/metrics`.

Is there a way to use fluentd data collector source in_http to get this metrics data every 30s and transfer/copy it to elasticsearch?